# Xcode gives random errors when removing a Obj-C header file from Swift project

Tags: ios, xcode

There's and old objective-c class that I use to create side menus. Now I 'm using a better swift class to do so. I've removed `#include "SWRevealViewController.h"` from my bridge file and removed the .h and .m files from project files. I also check for any references to the files in projects build settings and removed them too.

But after that, Xcode started to give random errors like `Use of undeclared type 'UICollectionViewCell'` and `Use of undeclared type 'CGFloat'; did you mean to use 'CGFloat'?`

Am I missing some point?

Comment: `import UIKit` is missing?

Comment: Maybe you had some imports in the `SWRevealViewController.h` that are now missing

Comment: @Sulthan No, It's not something like that.

Comment: @EmreA It looks to me like it is...